# Powershell: dealing with / in Registry property names

Tags: powershell, properties, registry

Given this (real) Registry path...

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\MrtCache\C:%5CProgram Files%5CWindowsApps%5C89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.6.0.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w%5Cresources.pri\1d3438f5876f755\6dfb7f2f\@{89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.6.0.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w?ms-resource://89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook/Files/Assets/AppLogo/Orion_Tiny.png}
```

where the property name is...

```
@{Microsoft.Office.OneNote_17.8625.20901.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.Office.OneNote/Files/images/OneNoteAppList.png}
```

I am trying to figure out how to properly deal with extracting the data value. I need to differentiate the path to the containing key from the property name, but because the property name contains `/` and Split-Path converts those to `\` and treats them as key delimiters, I get bad data out of that Cmdlet. From a programming standpoint the solution is to not start with a single path. However, I am somewhat constrained by existing data in XML files that provides only a single path. For 99.9% of cases, including drive and UNC file & folder paths, registry Key & Property paths as well as URL paths, Split-Path works. But for this very specific situation it fails. Is there a .NET solution that can be depended on? Or is this a case where there is no solution other than to break up the data and curse Microsoft for their inconsistency and incomplete solutions?
I get that this example is probably a situation I will never actually run into, but I have been burned before with things like assuming anything with an extension is a file and then finding someone (usually Autodesk) has decided to name a bunch of folders with a `.` in the name, causing code with that assumption about naming conventions to fail. So I am looking for a consistent way to deal with this, if one exists. Ideally in PS 5.1, not PS Core, as I cannot and will not demand that all my users upgrade to a new version of PowerShell to address such an edge case.

EDIT: I should also mention that a similar issue arrises when there is a `/` in a key name, and I want to verify that the key exists. `HKLM\Software\Key/Name` is a perfectly valid path, and Split-Path will soil itself every time and come back with `Name` as the leaf, not `Key/Name`. Because Split-Path doesn't actually understand what's valid as a registry key name, it seems.

Comment: You could write your own function with [`.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) and [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=net-5.0). This topic has been brought up [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5536) and the idea was to use specific path separators for each PowerShell Provider. It would be good to add a specific code example of `Split-Path` that you used or may want to use to the question.

Comment: @Ash, aha, that's a form of rolling my own I can get behind, as it's reasonably simple. I can use `($path -Split '\\')[-1]` to get what I know to be the Property name, the replace that with $null in the original full path to derive the full path of the parent. Interestingly, the `-Split` operator works, but I am having trouble with the `.Split()` method. Still, seems like a good way forward, at least to explore. EDIT: And I have the method working now too. Woot.

Comment: The fact that we don't have the ability to tell `Split-Path` that it's a Windows path not a Unix path and behave accordingly just reminds me of why I prefer a Mac. :)

Comment: I would recommend you use [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=net-5.0) in this case rather than `-Split "\\"`. Should be able to use it as so - `$Path.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)`. If you really want to get behind rolling on your own, I would be thinking of a `Split-RegistryPath` function that verifies the path and has switch parameters for Leaf and Parent))

Comment: RE: `The fact that we don't have the ability to tell Split-Path that it's a Windows path not a Unix path and behave accordingly just reminds me of why I prefer a Mac.` - Read the documentation for `DirectorySeparatorChar` (linked above) and [`AltDirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar?view=net-5.0). Windows supports both slashes as directory separators.

Comment: @Ash, the fact that it supports both, ALL THE TIME, even when only one or the other is appropriate, is the problem. Would be nice if the built in functionality offered that level of control. As for making my own `Split-RegistryPath` I will likely do that, but as a method in a RegistryPath class. I am refactoring to get away from Functions and pipeline pollution and such, and this will dovetail into that effort quite well. In the meantime, this limited approach will let me add some much needed features to my function based code in the meantime.

Comment: Why the need for a function for something so trivial??? `'HKLM:\Software\Key/Name'.Split("/")[-1]` will get you what you want. No 'pipeline pollution', just a basic string method

Comment: @Theo, true, for this specific case it's pretty easy. But I will have a few other things that I need to do with a registry path, so might as well make it a class and either make this a method, or just part of the constructor and the two parts are properties I can work with after.